# About protocols in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I have some questions about protocols in OBJ-C.
I often see lines that declare an id object with a protocol, for example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    id  <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    NSLog(@"%i",[secInfo numberOfObjects]);
    return [secInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

I don't understand the following line at all:

```
id  <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
```

1. What does " id   " mean?
2. What object does "objectAtIndex:section" return?
3. Why can I call "[secInfo numberOfObjects]" on the object?
   I mean, How's the method numberOfObjects exists?

I'm trying to lean CoreData but I can't actually continue without understanding this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does `id <ProtocolName>` mean?

It means "a pointer to any Objective-C object of which the class implements the `ProtocolName` protocol".

> What object does `objectAtIndex:section` return?

It returns objects of any class, which conform to the `<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>` protocol.

> Why can I call `[secInfo numberOfObjects]` on the object?

Why not?

> I mean, how does the method `numberOfObjects` exist?

The class of the returned object implements it.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering.
the first question was " what does id ( protocol name ) mean"
There was probably a problem with the editor.
And how the class of the return object Implements the numberOfObject?

Comment: @NoamSolovechick Okay, sorry, see update.

Comment: How is the class of the returned object implements it? I don't see anywhere in the code "numberOfObjects = 5" for example

Comment: @NoamSolovechick That's a method, not an instance variable or anything else... -.- Look for `- (int)numberOfObjects` or something similar.

Comment: It's a property: @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger numberOfObjects; What I didn't understand yet is if the returned object from objectAtIndex is converted or "translated" to the protocol. How's the protocol automatically knows the information about the section.

Comment: @NoamSolovechick In no way. A protocol is just for fooling the compiler. All the magic is done by the runtime.

Comment: I've noticed that when I delete the (protocol) from the id (protocol), the program still runs great. How's that?

Comment: @NoamSolovechick "A protocol is just for fooling the compiler" - it's not the declaration that matters, it's the implementation.

Comment: OK, I think I've understand everything except for one - When I delete the protocol from the declaration of the object, I don't even get a warning. Should it be like that? if so, why people still use the declaration of the protocol when creating an object when it's not necessary? Thank you very much for helping me with that!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Java background, think of `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` as a Java interface instead of a concrete class, and the function contents looking something like this:

```
NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo secInfo = this.fetchedResultsController.sections().objectAtIndex(section); 
System.out.println(secInfo.numberOfObjects());
return secInfo.numberOfObjects();
```

`numberOfObjects` can be called on `id  <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo` because that's the equivalent way of declaring this type of thing in Objective-C - it's not a specific class, but an "interface".

Answer (score 1):

1. `id` means "object of any type". `id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>` means "object of any type, as long as it implements the `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` protocol. A protocol is simply a list of method signatures, and if an object implements the protocol, that means it **has** to implement all the required methods of that protocol.
2. You don't really care. It could be any object that implements the `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` protocol, but you don't really care what type of object it is. All you need to know is that you can send it any required message from the `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` protocol.
3. `secInfo` is an object that implements the `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` protocol. If you go look at the protocol (cmd + click on the same will take you to its definition), you'll see that there's a message in the list called `numberOfObjects`. That means that there is a guarantee that any object that implements this protocol, will have implemented `numberOfObjects`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `id` is the generic type for a pointer to any Objective-C object. Declaring a variable of type `id` means it can reference any object; declaring a variable of type `id <SomeProtocol>` means it can reference an object of any class, but it must conform to `SomeProtocol`.
2. `[self.fetchedResultsController sections]` returns an array, in which each element is an object (whose class is unknown to you) implementing the `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` protocol and representing a section in your table. The method you're implementing wants to know the number of rows in the section whose index is passed in as the `section` parameter, so you call `objectAtIndex:section` on that array to get the `id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>` object representing that section.
3. You can call `[secInfo numberOfObjects]` because you've declared `secInfo` to reference an object which implements the `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` protocol; `numberOfObjects` is a method in that protocol. (And it actually works because, at runtime, it really is an object implementing that protocol, as expected from the documented behavior of `-[NSFetchedResultsController sections]`.)

> I'm trying to lean CoreData but I can't actually continue without understanding this.

Protocols aren't just a Core Data thing; if you're having trouble with them I recommend reading up on the [Objective-C language documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210).

Comment: Does the objectAtIndex:section contain all the properties that the protocol needs? I didn't understand how the properties are implemented. What happens behind the scenes that is implementing the onject that is returned from the "objectAtIndex" to the protocol? this is getting me crazy

Comment: The array on which you're calling `objectAtIndex:section` is [documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchedResultsController/sections) to contain only objects which conform to the `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` protocol. Because you know this (and you've told the compiler), you can safely call [any method declared in that protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

> What does " id " mean?

`id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>` is used to guarantee that the object conforms to the NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, so that if it's not, you get a compiler warning. It is useful for this.

> What object does "objectAtIndex:section" return?

`id` is the root of all pointer to objects.

Usually `id` is used when there isn't the certainty that the returned object will be of a type. The only thing known is that it conforms to the NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo protocol. So that's the case: you don't know which type of object will be returned, just that it conforms to that protocol.

> Why can I call "[secInfo numberOfObjects]" on the object? I mean, How's the method numberOfObjects exists?

Just see the documentation, it's implemented by the class.